# Does the PlayStation Store still work on PS Vita?

Tags: ps-vita

Is it true that PlayStation Store will not work on PS Vita?

Answer (score 0):

Sony confirmed on Monday that PlayStation Store access for the PlayStation 3, PlayStation Vita, and PlayStation Portable will end this summer. The PS3 and PS Vita stores close Aug. 27, 2021; the PSP’s remaining purchase functions will end on July 2, 2021.

But a few minutes ago, they confirmed that [Sony will not close digital stores on PS3 and PS Vita](https://nintendosmash.com/sony-will-not-close-digital-stores-on-ps3-and-ps-vita/)

Comment: This source isn’t confirmed by Sony.

Comment: https://blog.playstation.com/2021/04/19/playstation-store-on-ps3-and-ps-vita-will-continue-operations/